# hiding last 2 segments of IP using JS/Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a Haiku Sharing site and I'd like to be able to star out some IP address segments to help anonymize submission data before it's shown to other users.

If I needed a regexp that satisfied the following:

`24.210.99.1 becomes 24.210.*.*`

Is there a simple way to accomplish it?

Comment: Is the input always an IP string?

Comment: Is the IP always IPv4 or can it also be IPv6?

Comment: In other words, is the format of the string known beforehand, or does it need some pre-validation?

Comment: It will always appear as an ip string because I am taking it directly from the request headers.  Anticipating the format as #.#.#.#  (standard ipv4) will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281845/hiding-last-2-segments-of-ip-using-js-regexp/39281983#comment65898323_39281845):

> It will always appear as an ip string because I am taking it directly from the request headers. Anticipating the format as #.#.#.# (standard ipv4) will do the trick.

You may remove 2 last `.`+`digits` sequences and then append `.*.*`:

```js
var s = '24.210.99.1';
console.log(s.replace(/(?:\.\d+){2}$/, '') + ".*.*");
```

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?:\.\d+){2}`  - exactly 2 (`{2}`) sequences of:

  - `\.` - a literal dot symbol
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-regex way to mask the last 2 parts of an ip address:

```
var ip = '24.210.99.1'; // your IP

var arr = ip.split('.'); // split on DOT

arr[2] = arr[3] = '*'; // set 3rd and 4th element of array to *

var masked = arr.join('.'); // join by DOT again to get masked string
//=> "24.210.*.*"
```